# How to mount Android phone with jmtpfs on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, mount, fstab, android, mtp

I'm trying to mount and access files in my Asus Zenfone 2 Android phone connected via USB cable to a CentOS 6 (32 bit architecture) machine. As per [[these]](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP) instructions, I created a mount point in `/media/phone` and tried to access the device with `sudo jmtpfs phone` cmd. Unfortunately, I get this "Input/output error" msg:

```
[dolly@centos media]$ sudo jmtpfs --verbose phone 
Device 0 (VID=0b05 and PID=5f02) is a Asus Zenfone 2 ZE550ML (MTP).
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
fuse: bad mount point `phone': Input/output error
[dolly@centos media]$ ll
ls: cannot access phone: Permission denied
total 2
dr-x------. 2 dolly dolly 164 Jun 30  2015 cdrom_install
d?????????? ? ?     ?       ?            ? phone
[dolly@centos media]$
```

I know there's a directory called *Internal storage*, the same I can access if I connect the phone to a Windows machine:

```
[dolly@centos media]$ sudo ls phone 
Internal storage
[dolly@centos media]$ cd phone/"Internal storage"
bash: cd: phone/Internal storage: Permission denied
[dolly@centos media]$ sudo cd phone/"Internal storage"
sudo: cd: command not found
[dolly@centos media]$ ll
ls: cannot access phone: Permission denied
total 2
dr-x------. 2 dolly dolly 164 Jun 30  2015 cdrom_install
d?????????? ? ?     ?       ?            ? phone
[dolly@centos media]$
```

On a senior CentOS user's suggestion, I even created a `udev` rule, `91-android.rules`:

```
[dolly@centos media]$ ls -hl /etc/udev/rules.d/
total 60K
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.7K Nov 12  2010 60-fprint-autosuspend.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.1K Nov 11  2010 60-openct.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.1K Nov 11  2010 60-pcmcia.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  316 Jan 26 08:42 60-raw.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   56 Feb 29  2012 65-crystalhd.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  998 Dec  9 00:19 70-persistent-cd.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  590 Oct 27 00:11 70-persistent-net.rules
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  294 Jan  9 00:32 79-udev-epson.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  320 Nov 22  2016 90-alsa.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   83 Oct 15  2014 90-hal.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  108 Feb 19 12:32 91-android.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.5K Sep 12 23:56 97-bluetooth-serial.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  348 Nov 15 15:49 98-kexec.rules
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   54 May 11  2016 99-fuse.rules
[dolly@centos media]$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/91-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", ATTR{idProduct}=="5f02", MODE="0666", OWNER="dolly",GROUP="dolly"
[dolly@centos media]$
[dolly@centos media]$ sudo service udev reload 
udev: unrecognized service
[dolly@centos media]$
```

This is the output of `mount`:

```
[dolly@centos media]$ sudo mount
/dev/mapper/vg_hpdv6000-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/sda3 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/win type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
/dev/sr1 on /media/cdrom_install type udf (ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=501,gid=502,iocharset=utf8,umask=0077)
jmtpfs on /media/phone type fuse.jmtpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
[dolly@centos media]$
```

Finally, as of today this is what my **`/etc/fstab`** file looks like (I've thrown out a line that stated `jmtpfs /media/phone fuse nodev,allow_other,rw,user,noauto,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000    0    0`):

```
/dev/mapper/vg_hpdv6000-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=8b4c9d1b-6bcb-4bfc-b48f-146a415fb8f3 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_hpdv6000-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda1               /mnt/win        ntfs-3g         rw,umask=0000,defaults  0 0
```

Can you please help me understand why I'm unable to mount and therefore copy/paste files into the device, like it was a USB-connected mass storage device? `jmtpfs` used to work fine but then it started giving these "Input/output error" and "bad mount point" error. Can someone please help me out? What should I write on the `fstab` file?

PS.: I've noticed that when I connect the phone to the computer, a cd-rom icon appears on the CentOS 6 desktop. It's a directory containing a setup.exe file and an autorun.inf plain text file. The phone icon, on the other hand, is inaccessible. [image: two icons on the desktop as phone is connected to CentOS]

Comment: See this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409288/how-to-make-android-mtp-in-centos7-available-for-all-users

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work for me! Still getting a lot of error msg: `Device 0 (VID=0b05 and PID=5f02) is a Asus Zenfone 2 ZE550ML (MTP).
libusb_detach_kernel_driver() failed, continuing anyway...: No such file or directory
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
fuse: bad mount point ``phone/': Input/output error`

Comment: Try to boot from an old kernel (maybe a kernel bug)

Comment: GAD3R you're right! **It worked!** The only annoyance is that I must become root with `su -`, only then I can see the "Internal Storage" inside `/media/phone`. To unmount, as usual, I type: `fusermount -u /media/phone`. (Phone must be unlocked to access its internal filesystem). Thanks for your suggestion, GAD3R.

Answer (score 1):

Followed @GAD3R suggestion, just picked an alternative kernel among the ones listed at boot time. To mount: `sudo jmtpfs -o allow_other /media/phone`; to unmount: `fusermount -u /media/phone`.

Comment: In debian must install `mtp-tools and jmtpfs`,  see is detected with: `mtp-detect`, mount `jmtpfs  /home/user/tablet/` then for copy faster use `rsync -ah --progress src dest`

Comment: To unmount: `sudo umount /home/user/tablet/`